# how to write csv file in google app by using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, csv

I'm currently working on a project that is done in Java, on google appengine. i have above 2000 records

Appengine does not allow files to be stored so any on-disk representation objects cannot be used. Some of these include the File class.

I want to write data and export it to a few csv files, the user to download it.

How may I do this without using any File classes? I'm not very experienced in file handling so I hope you guys can advise me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just generate the csv in memory using a StringBuffer and then use `StringBuffer.toString().getBytes()` to get a byte array which can then be sent to your output stream.

For instance if using a servlet in GAE:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  buffer.append("header1, header2, header3\n");
  buffer.append("row1column1, row1column2, row1column3\n");
  buffer.append("row2column1, row2column2, row2column3\n");
  // Add more CSV data to the buffer

  byte[] bytes = buffer.toString().getBytes();

  // This will suggest a filename for the browser to use
  resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"myFile.csv\"");

  resp.getOutputStream().write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
```

More information about [GAE Servlets](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime)

More information about [Content-Disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Comment: Hi thanks for the replay.I am new with google app please tell me how to add the csv to buffer and after writing the csv file i want to download that file how can i do

Comment: thanks for the replay i added data to StringBuffer  but where i create the file after write file i want to downalodd the file.pleae help me

Answer (score 1):

You can store data in memory using byte arrays, stings and streams. For example,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream csv = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream printer = new PrintStream(csv);
printer.println("a;b;c");
printer.println("1;2;3");
printer.close();
csv.close();
```

Then in your Servlet you can serve your csv.toByteArray() as a stream. Some example is given here: [Implementing a simple file download servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442893/file-download-servlet).

Comment: Here where i give the file name.?I am new with google app and java

Answer (score -1):

You can use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net) library in Google App Engine.

Comment: hi thanks for the replay by using OpenCSV can i write the csv file in google app?

Comment: you can save it in BlobStore.

Comment: take a look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore

Comment: ya ..thanks for the replay meanas i want to read the user information from database and store the information in the for of csv file .now how can i create the csv file means google app not allow to create own file.

Comment: ya.thanks for the replay .i want to store the user information in csv file but in google app we can't write our own files .now how can i write the csv file

Comment: hi now i am using this code CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), '\t'); but here yourfile.csv means create my own file .but google app doesn't support to write csv files how can solve my problem