# How to export queried data from Google Cloud Datastore to csv using Java?

Tags: java, csv, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I have a use case where I need to perform the querying operation on the data stored in Google Cloud Datastore and display the results and provide a download link to the csv file of the same data.

I had gone through different documentations, but it dealt mostly with python whereas my implementation is in Java.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible way: you build your csv file in memory in a Cloud Endpoint by querying the Cloud datastore and print to a ByteArrayOutputStream, as shown hereafter:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream csvOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream printer = new PrintStream(csvOS);
printer.println("L1C1;L1C2;L1C3");
printer.println("L2C1;L2C2;L2C3");
printer.close();
```

Then you save the csv file to Cloud Storage and return the URL for downloading it, as I explained in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603225/3371862

An other possibility would be to stream the result through a Google App Engine servlet (i.e. you don't go through Cloud Endpoints). Have a look at [how to write csv file in google app by using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807336/how-to-write-csv-file-in-google-app-by-using-java)