# How to access local system files in jsp with hyperlink

Tags: java-6

I developed a web application using struts 1.2 , I need to access local files((C:\Testing) in jsp with a link format.When user clicks on a file name it automatically opens(no download option).File can be of any type(pdf,excel,.doc...) I tried

"><%=fileName%>

and

"><%=fileName%>

None of them worked..Any kind of help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I developed a web application using struts 1.2 , I need to access local files((C:\Testing\) in jsp with a link format.When user clicks on a file name it automatically opens(no download option).File can be of any type(pdf,excel,.doc...) I tried  <LI><A HREF="file:///<%=filePath%>"><%=fileName%></A></LI> and <LI><A HREF="file:<%=filePath%>"><%=fileName%></A></LI>

None of them worked..Any kind of help would be really appreciated. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your HTML ended up with a correctly formatted link "C:\Testing" a remote user's browser would just interpret that as pointing to *their* local C drive (if they even have one).

Instead you need to implement a file download servlet:

[Implementing a simple file download servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442893/implementing-a-simple-file-download-servlet)

And in your JSP insert a link to that servlet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....Sorry I want to connect to the shared drive(network), I am able to connect and open them with <a href="file:///<%=filePath%>" target="_blank"><%=fileName%></a>.....but I want when user clicks on them, IE won't ask for open,save,save as option it directly opens the file same as user clicks on any link in google for pdf it opens pdf direclty.