# How to add a link to a file in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a JSP page, and I would like to display a link that allows the user to download a file. That file is present on tomcat server, let's say in that directory :

C:\myDirectory\myFile

How can I download this file through a JSP ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you gave a link a in jsp like

```
C:\myDirectory\myFile
```

It tries to open the file on clients machine. Not the server machine.

Make a request to server. And write the stream to response.

A good start will be :[Implementing a simple file download servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442893/implementing-a-simple-file-download-servlet) And check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14281064/1927832)