# How to serve files outside of Spring MVC jar file

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

We have an annotation-based Spring MVC app with embedded Jetty.
I want to have a "downloads" directory next to our application jar file, and have requests for "/downloads/*" send files from that directory.

I thought it would be simple, but can't find a simple way to do it.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442893/implementing-a-simple-file-download-servlet

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I know I can implement the loading and sending of the file, but I want to make Jetty/Spring do that for me. How can tell Spring that I want a file to be sent? Where should I redirect the request to?