# Allowing download servlet only for users who are logged in

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I implemented a download servlet based on @wen's answer in [Implementing a simple file download servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442893/implementing-a-simple-file-download-servlet)

web.xml

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.myapp.servlet.DownloadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/download</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

DownloadServlet.java

```
public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {


    protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

         String id = request.getParameter("id");

         String fileName = "";
         String fileType = "";
```

How can I prevent the download servlet being activated by someone who is not logged in.

I have a `ClientSession` object that holds all the details of the login but I do not know how to access it from within the download servlet.

For instance, if I put a token in the request, then how could I validate this token against the ClientSession object.

Comment: Is the `ClientSession` stored inside `HttpSession`? You know, the one you can access with `request.getSession(false)`?

Comment: @Kayaman - you're right, I missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the client session from the HttpSession.

```
ClientSession clientSession = (ClientSession) request.getSession().getAttribute("client_session_info");
```

Naturally when you log in you must store your clientSession into the HttpSession like this:

```
session.setAttribute("client_session_info", clientSession);
```

I don't know how you log your user, but you should be able to access the http session object and store your data into it.