# Unable to change Tomcat's default file upload directory

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, web-applications

I am creating a sample webpage for file upload. I am specifying my own path. However, it always uploads the file in the .metadata folder of my workspace (eclipse workspace). Here is the code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
           boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
           if (isMultipart) {
               FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
               ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

                   List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                   Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
                   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                       FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
                       if (!item.isFormField()) {
                           String fileName = item.getName();    
                           String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/cloudnine/photobucket");
                           File path = new File(root);
                           if (!path.exists()) {
                               boolean status = path.mkdirs();
                           }
                           File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
                           System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                           item.write(uploadedFile);
                       }
                   }
               } 
           }
```

The file where it gets saved is:
tanmayaworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/cloudnine/cloudnine/photobucket/ESA.pdf

However I want it to be:
tanmayaworkspace/cloudnine/photobucket/ESA.pdf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45631136/2834978